# Thread security in sandboxed AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, multithreading

I have an application domain to host untrusted code/assembly. I solved all problems with security with security attributes and it works well. The untrusted code runs on dedicated thread. CLR is 2.0. This is what I have [AppDomainShell](http://code.google.com/p/robocode/source/browse/robocode/trunk/plugins/dotnet/robocode.dotnet.nhost/src/host/seed/AppDomainShell.cs) [AppDomainSeed](http://code.google.com/p/robocode/source/browse/robocode/trunk/plugins/dotnet/robocode.dotnet.nhost/src/host/seed/AppDomainSeed.cs), Shell is running in main domain, seed is trusted proxy/helper in untrusted domain.

I'm interested to **restrict creating new threads and changing priority**. At the moment my untrusted assembly could set ThreadPriority.Highest or kill operating system by creating 10k threads. There is [SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionflag%28VS.80%29.aspx) but that prevents just from advanced operations like Abort().

I was looking at Thread class implementation and there is no declarative security on C# API of it for those simple operations, rest of the implementation is native.

I guess I could use some Win32 functions to ban that on OS level. But how operating system recognizes the thread/code/assembly which is not trusted? [SetThreadPrincipal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setthreadprincipal%28VS.80%29.aspx) ?

Is there any API of CLR which could be abused ? I prefer solution without need for installation and portable to Mono, :-/ hmmm.

Any other ideas welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Jeremy asked for more context. So, I work on .NET host for Robocode robots, I'm not far from first release. As you may know Robocode is Java thing. You may also guess, that robot will try to cheat, that's malicious assembly. Now, I need it in same process because of speed. I need around 5000 calls per second between robocode battle core in Java and the robot in .NET. To achieve fast integration between java nad .NET that I started new project jni4net, because there is no free alternative. IKVM is not possibility as most of Robocode community is pure Java. More on my blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm considering another solution. Static analysis of CIL of untrusted assembly.
I could search thru all methods, properties, constructors. Recognize references to types. If I found reference to Thread type, I throw security exception and unload assembly.

I quite like work of Jb Evain. He created [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil), but that's quite heavyweight. He also drafted [CIL reader](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/04/30/reflection-based-cil-reader), just with .NET reflection.

I created [Linq over reflection](http://pavel.savara.sweb.cz/files/ReflectionRocks.cs) using CIL Reader. Usage look like this.

```
var myAssembly = typeof (Program).Assembly;
foreach (Type usedType in myAssembly.GetUsedTypes())
{
    if (typeof (Thread).IsAssignableFrom(usedType) ||
        typeof (ThreadPool).IsAssignableFrom(usedType) ||
        typeof (ThreadPriority).IsAssignableFrom(usedType)
        )
    {
        throw new SecurityException("Thread usage is banned here!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pavel, why did you give up the 'runtime' version? Did it turn out to be impossible without hosting the CLR?

Comment: Yes, there was not enough control provided by the sandbox without hosting API.

Comment: Wouldn't it be reasonably easy to bypass this by using reflection?

Comment: See ReflectionPermission and ban it for app domain, among others.

Comment: The documentation for ReflectionPermission suggests that even in the most restrictive mode, it doesn't prevent use of reflection altogether, just whether protected/private members can be reflected upon for example.

Comment: It seems you are right. Any suggestions ? Maybe search for use of Activator in my LINQ too ?

Comment: There are unfortunately so many ways to potentially access methods that would be difficult to detect/restrict (some that might also have legitimate uses) that I think you're going to need to think of another mechanism. A few other examples I thought of: Reflection.Emit and Expressions could be use to access threading methods directly, and parallel-LINQ (which is now part of .NET 4), and even Timers could be used to indirectly spawn additional threads. No doubt there are others too.

Answer (score 0):

Threads run within a single process, and you should be safe as your untrusted code can't change the priority of the process. (See MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass.aspx) for details.)

I'm not sure that even creating 10k threads within a process would necessarily kill Windows - at least, not any version of Windows above Windows NT. Your process would almost certainly stop running, however, so you might want to consider two *processes* and use a mechanism such as remoting or WCF to communciate between them.

Comment: Unfortunately I need fast calls into other (Java) part of the application running in same process. So another process and any slow message interface is not solution.

Comment: Then I think you need to say more about what it is you're trying to achieve and why you assume a malicious assembly might stop it.

Comment: Jeremy I gave more context above. Boosted thread priority is strong competitive advantage for robot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [HostProtectionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.hostprotectionattribute.aspx) is the right thing for limiting thread manipulation by untrusted code?

Comment: Documentation says that the host protection is not tested if you don't run native host. I think it's rather attribute for static analysis tool, not the runtime. Maybe I understood incorrectly...

Comment: If you host the runtime yourself then it acts like a LinkDemand.

Comment: I'm looking at it now. Found this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/10/12/480186.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2005/10/13/480210.aspx
Now I wonder how to achieve that from inside running CLR.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaf1h1h5%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: It was interesting, but not possible. CLR till v4 can't be twice in same process. I tried code below, but there is restriction in CLR hosting code. It could be verified in Rotor sources.
I wrapped several COM interfaces from mscoree.h

CLRRuntimeHostClass host = new CLRRuntimeHostClass();

ICLRControl icc;

host.GetCLRControl(out icc);

// this throws COM exception invalid operation,
// if CLR is already started

icc.GetCLRManager(ref IID_ICLRHostProtectionManager, out hpmp);

Comment: Anyway, this is not guaranteed security. Search for "(HPA)" in this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2004/02/21/77595.aspx